# Hide Sphinx subsections from main TOCTree

Tags: python-sphinx, sections, toctree

Is it possible to hide one (or all) subsections present in a RST file from the main TOCTree?

Let me describe a little more:

**index.rst**

```
:doc:`Label <path/to/rst/file>`
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

.. toctree::

   Label <path/to/rst/file>
   Label <path/to/rst/file>

   Label of Children TOCTree <path/to/rst/children/file>
```

**children/file.rst**

```
Children Title
==============

.. toctree::

   Label of Grandchildren 1
   Label of Grandchildren 2


Subsection 1
------------

Subsection 2
------------

Subsection 3
------------
```

These files, after built, will result, in main TOCTree:

- Label
- Label
- Label of Children

  - Label of Grandchildren 1
  - Label of Grandchildren 2
  - Subsection 1
  - Subsection 2
  - Subsection 3

And I would like to hide the Subsections, keeping only the TOCTrees, as many and as deep as I want. E.g:

- Label
- Label
- Label of Children

  - Label of Grandchildren 1
  - Label of Grandchildren 2

But, if the hyperlink associated to **Label of Children** is clicked, the Subsections are listed as usual;

Comment: Maybe the `titlesonly` option is what you are looking for. See http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/toctree.html.

Comment: I tried it but it does exactly the opposite of what I want, keeping the titles and hiding the childrens TOCTrees.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-TOC headings within a Restructuredtext page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069405/non-toc-headings-within-a-restructuredtext-page)

Answer (score 12):

This took me awhile to figure out, but I think I finally got it. The "trick" is that you need to set directives in both the parent rst which contains the toc and the child rst which contains the section.

For me, I added `:maxdepth:1` and `:titlesonly:` to the toc in the parent rst, and then `:titlesonly:` to the toc in the child, and that works perfectly. That allows me to have hierarchical subsection formatting in the child which is rendered properly that does not show up in the TOC.

Comment: *Just* what I needed. I actually specifically want `:maxdepth: 2` in my `index.rst` toctree, but even still `:titlesonly:` worked just fine for suppressing the subsections I've defined in the child pages.

Answer (score 9):

The [rubric](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-rubric) directive may achieve what you want.

> .. rubric:: title
>
> This directive creates a paragraph heading that is not used to create a table of contents node.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `maxdepth` parameter of [`toctree`](http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/toctree.html) to set how deep the TOC is:

```
.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing ------------------ to ***************** for Subsection 1 etc. Also, you can make multiple toctrees each with their own maxdepth, eg

```
.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 2

    Label <path/to/rst/file>
    Label <path/to/rst/file>

.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 1
    Label of Children TOCTree <path/to/rst/children/file>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own tags

Where you want your header type

```
|start-h3| My Title |end-h3|
```

At the end of the file write

```
.. |start-h3| raw:: html

     <h3>

.. |end-h3| raw:: html

     </h3>
```